# install robots.txt to wordpress website admin

Tags: plugins, seo, robots.txt

our website is http://syno-int.co.kr
and using wordpress. 
I tried to install robots.txt to plugin section, 
but when I put zip file in it, it shows like this.

Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/07. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

What should I do? Please let me know. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions, you can try:

**Solution 1 – Changing Uploads Directory In WordPress Settings**

If you have moved your WordPress to a new hosting recently. There is great chance that path to your WordPress uploads directory is incorrect. Follow below steps to correct/verify settings.

1. **Sign in** as admin on WordPress
2. click on **Settings** tab
3. select **Media**.
4. Under the section titled Uploading Files, you should see a field named **Store uploads** in this folder. Now check the path to Uploads directory.

[image]

5. Once you are sure that uploads directory in WordPress settings is correct press **Save** button and try to upload files again.

**Alternate Method for Solution 1:**

If you’re unable to see the uploads directory field in WordPress admin area. Use File Manager or FTP and open up the `wp-config.php` file for editing. And add the following code:

`define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );`

This code should be included **before this line**:

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Now try to upload media files again. If you still get error proceed to Option 2.

It is may be better to reset the folder permissions of your uploads folder. For this, you can use an FTP client, like FileZilla or File Manger as well. Follow these steps to reset folder permissions using FileZilla:

1. Connect to your account with FileZilla.
2. Go to WordPress installation directory (in most cases it’s `public_html`) and open `wp-content` folder.
3. Once inside, right-click on the **Uploads** directory.
4. Click on **File Permissions**, which will prompt open a dialog box.
5. Here, find the Numeric value field, and enter **755**.
6. Check the **Recurse into subdirectories** option if not already checked.
7. Select **Apply** to directories only from the radio buttons.
8. Click **OK**.

[image]

Hope it helps! :)